# mule/java - reading a property file which is inside of jar dependency from java class

Tags: java, jar, mule, properties-file

Here my requirement is, I have created one mule application which has java class. Some of the values which I don't want to keep it as a hard-coded so I am trying to externalize it. I kept this values in mule-app.properties file and used FileInputStream as below.

```
String propFileName = "src/main/app/mule-app.properties"
Properties property = new Properties();
property.load(new FileInputStream(propFileName));
```

But this code needs to be deployed on CloudHub; there its failing saying that file not found. I Tried with give path of the file name as

```
String propFileName = "target/classes/mule-app.properties"
```

for both the cases its running fine locally but gives same results on CloudHub as "File Not Found".

What could be the solution?

Another thing is I have a common code in which we are keeping all the properties related to different environment. Packaging of this common code is in the form of jar. So, can I keep properties which I am using in above code and read it from jar itself.

If Yes, then How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this we can do one thing. Using expression component set variable for each property you want to fetch.

```
<expression-component doc:name="setVariable"><![CDATA[flowVars.clientId="${poc.clientId}";]]></expression-component>
```

This flow Variable is accessible in Java class irrespective of where it is been kept i.e. mule-app.properties or on cloudhub run time properties.

In Java class, using below code we can read this Flow Variable.

```
String clientId = eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("clientId");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deploy in cloudhub and externalize your properties file better use Cloudhub properties tab to externalize the values.
ref:- https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/deploying-to-cloudhub#properties-tab

And in Java class you can pick the properties value using :- `System.getProperty("yourpropertykey")`
simple as that :)

Regarding keeping properties file in common jar app, you need to use `<context:property-placeholder/>` to pick up the properties file from the classpath of the common jar application and can use it in your host application mule flow

Answer (score -1):

Use the below sample code it should work.

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("C:\Users\userName\
      AnypointStudio\workspace\test\src\main\resources\my-app1.propertie");

Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(fi)
```

Comment: It will definitely work but it won't be able to read the properties after deployment on cloud or on-prem. This is not the good practice to write entire path location.